# Child iframe not receiving touch events

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, safari, webkit

I have a code as follows;

```
<div id="scroller" style="width: 50%; overflow: auto;"> 
            <iframe height="100%" id="iframe" scrolling="no" width="100%" id="iframe" src="responses.html" /> 
        </div>
```

Now I want the iframe data table to scroll within the main page on the iPad..

I have used a js on the iframe page to listen for touch events touchstart, touchmove, etc

But for some reasons these events never get fired on the iPad..

I also tried this;

```
var startY = 0;
    var startX = 0;
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", function (event) {
    alert(11);
        parent.window.scrollTo(0, 1);
        startY = event.targetTouches[0].pageY;
        startX = event.targetTouches[0].pageX;
    });
    document.addEventListener("touchmove", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var posy = event.targetTouches[0].pageY;
        var h = parent.document.getElementById("scroller");
        var sty = h.scrollTop;
        var posx = event.targetTouches[0].pageX;
        var stx = h.scrollLeft;
        h.scrollTop = sty - (posy - startY);
        h.scrollLeft = stx - (posx - startX);
        startY = posy;
        startX = posx;
    });
```

Could you please help me. Thank you...

Comment: Please suggest something..if not the exact solution..at least some direction..

Comment: Using this javascript on the main page works? If yes, maybe you could change your code so that responses.html (or the 'body' content of that page) gets loaded using an ajax call?  
The response you would then insert directly into `scroller`.
So basically.. Is the iframe a must?

Comment: Shouldn't the IFRAME be able to scroll without any scripting? Try touching anywhere inside the frame to focus it, and then try scrolling.

Comment: That is the whole point of this question..safari on ios 4.3 does not support iframe scrolling natively..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Take out the duplicate `id` tag from the iframe:

```
<iframe height="100%" id="iframe" scrolling="no" width="100%" src="responses.html" />
```

2) add this to your css:

```
#scroller {
z-index:-1;
}

#iframe {
z-index:1;
}
```

and see if that has an effect. If it doesn't you can always use AJAX.

Make sure that jquery is included on the page, then:

```
<script>    
$.ajax({
      url: "responses.html",
      cache: false,
      success: function(html){
        $("#results").append(html);
      }
    });
</script>

<div id="results" height="100%" width="100%"></div>
```